# Do Regional Central Banks have API's?

Tags: market-data

Do Regional Central Banks such as the Federal Reserve and ECB have API's to access their Statistics? I've been searching all day and haven't been able to find them. They seem to provide most of their data in CSV Files or one has to carry out some web-scraping.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

The Federal Reserve bank of St Louis has a widely used and popular application called FRED http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/ which is a fairly rich data source for US macro time series data considering that it's freely available! Check out their API https://api.stlouisfed.org for more info.